# Folktale / fantasyland Maybe not working as expected

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, monads, fantasyland, folktale

Reading [Frisbys guide to functional programming](https://mostly-adequate.gitbooks.io/mostly-adequate-guide/), currently on the chapter about `Maybe`.  In the [appendix](https://mostly-adequate.gitbooks.io/mostly-adequate-guide/appendix_b.html) the book suggests using either [folktale](http://folktale.origamitower.com/) or [fantasyland](https://github.com/fantasyland/fantasy-land).

However in both libraries `Maybe` doesn't seem to be work as described in the book.

```
const Maybe = require('folktale/maybe')
// const Maybe = require('fantasy-options')
const {
    flip, concat, toUpper, path, pathOr, match, prop
} = require('ramda')

console.log(
    Maybe.of('Malkovich Malkovich').map(match(/a/ig))
)
// Just(['a', 'a'])

Maybe.of(null).map(match(/a/ig))
//******************************
// TypeError: Cannot read property 'match' of null
//******************************
// Nothing

Maybe.of(
    { name: 'Boris' }
).map(prop('age')).map(add(10))
// Nothing

Maybe.of(
    { name: 'Dinah', age: 14 }
).map(prop('age')).map(add(10))
// Just(24)
```

In this example copied from the book, the first statement works correctly, but the second gets a `TypeError`.  This seems to completely go against the purpose of `Maybe`.  Or am I misunderstanding something?

[Example repl.it](https://repl.it/@billjohnston/IncredibleMediocreKeys)

Comment: `Maybe.of` always constructs a `Maybe`. Perhaps look at `Maybe.fromNullable` which constructs either a `Maybe` or a `Nothing` depending on the input

Comment: `Maybe` isn't able to replace `null` on the language level. However, `Maybe` has a similar role to `null` and hence you can replace it on the application level. `null` wrapped in a `Maybe` is still `null` and will cause type errors for lifted functions.

Comment: @ftor yes, but Isn't it supposed to skip running the .map fn if its value is null? 
 `map(fn) { return this.isNothing ? this : Maybe.of(fn(this.$value)); }` I thought this was the entire purpose of `Maybe`

Comment: You can construct a type that has certain behavior for `null`. But then you lose parametric polymorphism for this type. I am not experienced enough to assess the consequences, though. Maybe it is not too bad to make an exception for `null`. Anyway, look into parametricity.

Comment: @BillJohnston The whole point of `Maybe` is to provide a more elegant _alternative_ to `null`, not a wrapper for `null` values. It's not `Maybe`'s job to recognize `null` and turn them into `Nothing`s. Frisby's book uses the (somewhat hacky) approach of treating a `Maybe` containing a `null` as `Nothing`, but I don't think that's typical and that's pretty much an implementation detail. In Folktale, the way to create `Nothing` is to use `Maybe.Nothing()`, but Folktale also provides `Maybe.fromNullable` (already mentioned above) which turns `null` and `undefined` into `Nothing`.

Answer (score 2):

**Update: August 2019**

Pleased you asked this question, I was also surprised initially at the difference in behaviour. As others have responded, it comes down to the way the [Frisby Mostly Adequate Guide implementation](https://mostly-adequate.gitbooks.io/mostly-adequate-guide/appendix_b.html#maybe) was coded. The "irregular" implementation detail is related to the way in which `isNothing`s function implementation is shielding the null or undefined `value` passed in using `Maybe.of`:

```
get isNothing() {
    return this.$value === null || this.$value === undefined;
 }
```

If you refer to other implementations - then using `Maybe.of()` to create your `Maybe` does allow you to pass in a `null` or `undefined` for the `Just` case's value and actually print for example `Maybe.Just({ value: null })`

Instead, when using Folktale, create the `Maybe` using `Maybe.fromNullable()` which will allocate a `Just` or `Nothing` according to the value input.

Here's a working version of the code provided:

```
const Maybe = require("folktale/maybe");

const {
  flip,
  concat,
  toUpper,
  path,
  pathOr,
  match,
  prop,
  add
} = require("ramda");

console.log(Maybe.of("Malkovich Malkovich").map(match(/a/gi)));
//-> folktale:Maybe.Just({ value: ["a", "a"] })

console.log(Maybe.fromNullable(null).map(match(/a/gi)));
//-> folktale:Maybe.Nothing({  })
```

Finally, here's a demonstration implementation of Maybe, codified to use `fromNullable` (similar to the Folktale implementation). I took this reference implementation from what I consider a highly recommended book - [Functional Programming In JavaScript by Luis Atencio](https://www.manning.com/books/functional-programming-in-javascript). He spends much of Chapter 5 explaining this clearly.

```
/**
 * Custom Maybe Monad used in FP in JS book written in ES6
 * Author: Luis Atencio
 */ 
exports.Maybe = class Maybe {
    static just(a) {
        return new exports.Just(a);
    }
    static nothing() {
        return new exports.Nothing();
    }
    static fromNullable(a) {
        return a !== null ? Maybe.just(a) : Maybe.nothing();
    }
    static of(a) {
        return Maybe.just(a);
    }
    get isNothing() {
        return false;
    }
    get isJust() {
        return false;
    }
};


// Derived class Just -> Presence of a value
exports.Just = class Just extends exports.Maybe {
    constructor(value) {
        super();
        this._value = value;
    }

    get value() {
        return this._value;
    }

    map(f) {
        return exports.Maybe.fromNullable(f(this._value));
    }

    chain(f) {
        return f(this._value);
    }

    getOrElse() {
        return this._value;
    }

    filter(f) {
        exports.Maybe.fromNullable(f(this._value) ? this._value : null);
    }

    get isJust() {
        return true;
    }

    toString () {
        return `Maybe.Just(${this._value})`;
    }
};

// Derived class Empty -> Abscense of a value
exports.Nothing = class Nothing extends exports.Maybe {
    map(f) {
        return this;
    }

    chain(f) {
        return this;
    }

    get value() {
        throw new TypeError("Can't extract the value of a Nothing.");
    }

    getOrElse(other) {
        return other;
    }

    filter() {
        return this._value;
    }

    get isNothing() {
        return true;
    }   

    toString() {
        return 'Maybe.Nothing';
    }
};
```

Comment: Nice answer! Can you also tell something about this case: `Maybe.of("foo").map(s => null).map(s => s.toUpperCase())` (assuming `s => null` is a function that can return either a string or a null). My intuition was that if a function in the chain of `map`s returns a null, the chain must stop. But now I see I was wrong. Still, I'm wondering, is there an idiomatic way to stop the chain in such cases? I tried to return `Maybe.Nothing()` instead of `null`, but it just wraps `Nothing` into `Just`, so the upper-case function gets instance of `Nothing`.